# iOS Bluetooth Device in pheripheral mode send request to one central device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

iOS Bluetooth Smart.

We have few central devices and one pheripheral devices. How to send from pheripheral device request to one of centrals?

iOS support something like "direct advertising"?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth peripherals are supposed to be used as advertisers that the Centrals can find and connect to. Not the other way around. Basically you need to set up your peripheral with service/s that the Central is scanning for. After the central discovers the peripheral, it can then choose to connect, and then exchange additional data between the devices.

Check out the [Bluetooth Developer Site](https://developer.bluetooth.org/) for more information.

Comment: This issue does not affect bultooth but IOS and Cocoa framework. Direct advertising exist and work but framework form Apple doesn't supoprt this.